# Ruby inconsistency in time calculations between Date and Date.to_time operations

Tags: ruby, datetime

Test setup

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):007:0> require 'active_support/all'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> start = Date.new(2016,10,1)
=> #<Date: 2016-10-01 ((2457663j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):003:0> finish = Date.new(2016,11,1)
=> #<Date: 2016-11-01 ((2457694j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

I expect that both `finish-start.div` to return 1 (or 0) but mostly be consistent. Yet oddly when I do use Date objects it returns 0 but when I take the same Date object and convert it to_time it returns 1.

```
irb(main):008:0> (finish-start).div(1.month)
=> 0
irb(main):009:0> start + 1.month <= finish
=> true

irb(main):010:0> (finish.to_time - start.to_time).div(1.month)
=> 1
irb(main):011:0> start.to_time + 1.month <= finish.to_time
=> true
```

Why is that? What is going on?

Comment: Daylight saving time?

Answer (score 1):

`finish - start` invokes [`Date#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-2D) and returns the number of days, i.e. 31:

```
finish - start
#=> (31/1)
```

`finish.to_time - start.to_time` on the other hand invokes [`Time#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-2D) and returns the number of seconds, i.e. 60 × 60 × 24 × 31:

```
finish.to_time - start.to_time
#=> 2682000.0
```

`1.month` returns a `ActiveSupport::Duration` instance equivalent to the number of seconds in a 30-day month i.e. 60 × 60 × 24 × 30:

```
1.month.to_i
#=> 2592000

1.month == 2592000
#=> true
```

With the above in mind, your calculations are equivalent to:

```
     31 / 2592000 #=> 0
2682000 / 2592000 #=> 1
```

Comment: ohh, I almost in time :(

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate

```
finish-start
#=> (61/1) #(days/hours+1)
```

and

```
finish.to_time - s.to_time
#=> 2592000 #seconds
```

for check result of `div` you can use `divmod`

```
(finish-start).divmod(1.month)
=> [0, (31/1)]
(finish.to_time - start.to_time).divmod(1.month)
=> [1, 90000.0]
```

to make it work the same, you can use the next:

```
(finish-start).days.to_i.divmod(1.month.to_i)
#=> [1, 86400]
```